# How can I insert the value of some variables into a string in my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
BEGIN
   ;THROW 50003,'UserTestStatusAction - Did not find a row matching Role, Current and New status',1
END
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
BEGIN
   ;THROW 50003,'UserTestStatusAction - Did not find a row matching Role' + @Role + ', Current' +  @CurrentTestStatusId + 'and New status ' + @NewTestStatusId,1
END
```

I also tried this:

```
BEGIN
   ;THROW 50003,CONCAT('UserTestStatusAction - Did not find a row matching Role',@Role,', Current',@CurrentTestStatusId,'and New status ',@NewTestStatusId),1
END
```

How can I insert the values of @Role, @CurrentTestStatusId and @NewTestStatusId into this string? I have tried the + operator but this gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Don't make us guess, tell us what the error is. Why do you have a leading semicolon?

Comment: @SeanLange - I am not sure why there is a leading semicolon as it is not my code. The stored procedure has leading semicolons before all the THROW words.  Perhaps someone here can suggest why. I just left it there as it seems not to give a problem.

Comment: @SeanLange - I used the + to join up the parts of the code but it gives me an error saying "Incorrect syntax"

Comment: They are statement terminators not beginninators. I know it isn't your code but they can be removed.

Comment: That's nice. Can you share some details? Like datatypes or the actual error message? I can't see your screen but this is most certainly a simple fix once you share enough information.

Comment: What are the datatypes of your variables??

Comment: @SeanLange Because `THROW` requires the previous statement to be terminated in a semicolon. Bit like `WITH` to define a CTE, people start it with a semicolon just to be sure =)

Comment: All are INT datatypes

Comment: Finally enough information. You can't concatenate ints and varchar. You have to cast the ints as varchar.

Comment: @TT I figured that was why. Of course it also forces dropping what should be a single statement inside a begin/end block. >.<

Comment: @SeanLange and the irony -- inside a begin end block it does not have a prior statement to not be terminated by a `;`  Basically a crapy style on many levels.  Why not just have the prior statement end in a `;`?

Comment: The leading ; is there to ensure the the previous statement is properly terminated. THROW is not a reserved key word so could be interpreted as an optional parameter for a previous statement if it is not properly terminated.

For example
ROLLBACK TRAN
THROW would try to rollback a transaction named throw and would fail. Because error catching is boiler plate code that is frequently reused especially by people who may not fully understand it I've seen lots of recommendations to always precede THROW with ; just to make sure that the previous statement is terminated.

Comment: @SeanLange - I tried the casting suggested but it gives errors. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Marilou look at my answer it has the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you can have expressions as parameters when calling THROW or other similar functions (all parameters must be constants or variables).

Anyway, I suggest to compute your string beforehand, as this also allows to handle NULL values accordingly:

```
DECLARE @error VARCHAR(MAX) = 
   'UserTestStatusAction - Did not find a row matching Role ' + ISNULL(CAST(@Role AS VARCHAR(100)), '') + 
   ', Current ' + ISNULL(CAST(@CurrentTestStatusId AS VARCHAR(50)), '') + 
   'and New status ' + ISNULL(CAST(@NewTestStatusId AS VARCHAR(50)), '');

THROW 51000, @error, 1;
```

This prevents nullifying all the string if any of your tokens is NULL.

Comment: This is better than mine.  But why not have @error be VARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: Yes, MAX is safer. I usually try to put an appropriate size for VARCHAR, as in the tables may lead to performance problems. However, in this case it is safer to have it as max (I think the string is silently truncated when maximum size is reached). Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Role  varchar(20) = 'admin';

DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = 'UserTestStatusAction - Did not find a row matching Role ' + @Role

;THROW 51000, @msg, 1;
```

Comment: U can use only const varchar or variable

Comment: and yes, before throw u have to place semicolumn

Comment: wow really... you had a chance to put a semi-colon at the end of the line and instead you put it at the start of the next line.  Why?

Comment: You can add ";" after previous line. But MS Sql do not distinguish between space and new line.  And You know that previous line must be ended with ";" before Throw statement. To not forget - You simply put ";" BEFORE throw. Nothing more.......